# PHP: Condition for field key value

Tags: php, conditional-statements

How do I declare a condition for a field key value. I have a custom field and part of this statement is used to display its value...

```
function SINGLE_CUSTOMFIELDS($post,$FieldValues){

    global $wpdb,$PPT;$row=1;

    if($FieldValues ==""){ 
        $FieldValues = get_option("customfielddata");
    }

    if(is_array($FieldValues)){

        print "<div class='offer-info'>";

        foreach($FieldValues as $key => $field){

            if(isset($field['show']) && $field['enable'] == 1 ){                 

            $imgArray = array('jpg','gif','png', 'swf');

            $value = $PPT->GetListingCustom($post->ID,$field['key'] );

            if(is_array($value) || strlen($value) < 1){   }else{

                if($field['key'] == "Zipcode"){

                print "<div style='display:none'><p><br />"; 
                print "<b>".$field['name']."</b></p><p><br />";

                }
```

I want to set a condition for the field key Zipcode that is equal to a value (Ex. 33138)

I was thinking that it would be something like this:

```
if($field['key'] == "Zipcode" => "33138"){

                print "Print something"; 

                }
```

But apparently this is wrong. I would appreciate if someone showed how to set a condition for a specific field key value. And also for multiple field keys in the condition statement.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want an array with a key of "Zipcode" and a value of "33138", or ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Im still learning php. I updated the with beginning of the function being used. I want to set a condition for the Zipcode field key when it is equal to a certain number.

Comment: You should show us what the value of `$FieldValues` is (i.e. the structure of the array, best with `var_export`).

Comment: @Felix: The values are to be entered by the end user. There's no set values.

Comment: @gdinari: That is not what I mean. You are iterating of the array `$FieldValues` and you just should have given us an example what the structure of the array is. How can we tell you how to access the array if we don't know it's structure?

Comment: What Felix is trying to say is you should use `var_export` to show us the structure of your array. For example, `var_export($FieldValues)` which would then output are result that shows us the underlying structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure this is what you mean by "field key", but how about accessing it by name?

```
if ($field["Zipcode"] == "33138") {
    print "Print something";
}
```